# prompt a string. identify it in an array, and if so, give back the info written as a fact of that string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have already defined an array. What I want to do is identify if the word given by the user is in my array and, if so, give the user back the info that the array has with regard that word (string)

```
var countryNameArray = [{
  name: 'France',
  fact: 'they speak french'
}, {
  name: 'Belgium',
  fact: 'they speak french or dutch'
},];

if (countryNameArray.indexOf(WordGiven[countryNameArray])) {
  console.info(countryNameArray.includes(WordGiven));
  alert(countryNameArray.name, + + , countryNameArray.fact)
} else {
  alert ('I did not understand. Please give me a Country Name')
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, what you're asking is that given a string, you would like to get the object inside countryNameArray whose name matches the given string.

One way to achieve that is using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var countryNameArray = [
    {
        name: 'France',
        fact: 'they speak french'
    },
    {
        name: 'Belgium',
        fact: 'they speak french or dutch'
    },
];

var matchingCountries = countryNameArray.filter(c => c.name === WordGiven);
```

From filter, you will have an array where name matches WordGiven, from which you can handle in any way you'd like, for example

```
if (matchingCountries.length === 0) {
    console.log('No matching country found');
} else {
    var firstMatch = matchingCountries.first();
    console.log(firstMatch.name, + + , firstMatch.fact);
}
```

EDIT: After seeing the other answer using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), that is a much better fit for what you're trying to achieve. Substitute filter for find and you wouldn't need to do the whole .first() stuff.

Comment: actually, your solution with `.filter()` isn't bad as the `countryNameArray` might have many objects which have the same `name`. However, if you do use this, it would be better to looper through the `matchingCountries` array to output all matches, rather than just the first one ;)

Comment: @NickParsons Agreed, however I was trying to emphasise more on the `.filter()` part and sort of say after that "you can do whatever you like, for example...". Maybe I should change the example then to highlight what you've said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the object with `name` matching your user input. Then you can use [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the properties (`name` and `fact` from your javascript object) from your found object.

See working example below:

```js
const countryNameArray = [{
    name: 'France',
    fact: 'they speak french'
  },
  {
    name: 'Belgium',
    fact: 'they speak french or dutch'
  },
],
wordGiven = prompt("Enter a country name");

if(countryObj = countryNameArray.find(({name}) => name === wordGiven)) {
  const {name, fact} = countryObj; // get the name and fact properties from countryObj
  alert(name + ': ' + fact);
} else {
  alert('I did not understand. Please give me a Country Name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating a function and passing the country name as a parameter we can achieve this using the **find()** method.

```
const countryNameArray = [{
    name: 'France',
    fact: 'they speak french'
},
{
    name: 'Belgium',
    fact: 'they speak french or dutch'
    },
];

const result = (name) => {
    let country = countryNameArray.find(obj => obj.name === name);
    if (country) {
        alert(`${country.name} ${country.fact}`); // 'France they speak french'
    } else {
        alert ('I did not understand. Please give me a Country Name')
    }
}

result('France');
```